# FFMPEG with FIFO to RTMP server breaks playback

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, fifo, wowza

I'm trying to use FFMPEG's FIFO in order to add auto-reconnect to an RTMP stream.

`fmpeg -i myFile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee  "[f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://rtmp/blah`

Whilst the command seems to run fine, I'm having issues with playback of the stream. RTMP playback is without issue, but HLS seems to return a load of errors messages.

`[hls @ 0x7fd14a838000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`

`[h264 @ 0x7fd14b03dc00] sps_id 32 out of range
Invalid UE golomb code=   0 aq=   20KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

[NULL @ 0x7fd14a810400] pps_id 3199971767 out of range
Invalid UE golomb code`

If I stream without FIFO, everything works perfectly. Media server is Wowza, latest version. FFMPEG is latest version.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @kamprath I'm afraid not. I haven't revisited this for a long while though. Sorry.